# Code Igniter not running the method in the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I have a form in a view called login_view that I would like to target a function in the Login controller.

For my form in login_view I have `echo form_open('/Login/validate_credentials');`

In my Login.php controller I have:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate_credentials(){
        $this->load->view('welcome2');
    }
}
?>
```

When I submit the form from the browser, instead of loading the welcome2 view like I expect, it tries to load the URL of:

`localhost/project/Login/validate_credentials`

and I just see the default page for WAMP.

It's my first day in Code Igniter so I'm sure the answer is simple.

Comment: are you adding url helper  $this->load->helper('url'); in the controller __construct(),seems you are not

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't understand how to use what you said to fix my problem

Comment: On your controller files you do not need to close php ?> at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your controller construct by this:

```
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('url','text','html','form','string'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added that line but it did not appear to make any difference.

Comment: It goes to the same URL and still just shows me the default WAMP page

Comment: wamp page? ok let me know Is your apache has rewrite mode on and show me your routes and config['base_url']

Comment: Ah! I knew it was simple. I had re-installed WAMP recently and forgot to turn back on rewrite_module. Now everything works, thank you!!!